# NetworkError: 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Ao Enviar um post recebi pelo retrofit no log a mensagem NetworkError: 400 Bad Request.

No Ambiente de Desenvolvimento nenhum erro ocorre, os dados são sincronizados do dispositivo para o Servidor ( Tomcat ) de minha rede interna com sucesso.

Publiquei o sistema, no dispositivo eu configurei a URL, e ao tentar transmitir os dados recebo o erro NetworkError: 400 Bad Request

```
http://200.187.136.7:8080/nova/fw.rule?sys=TSE&usuario=teste&metodo=fw_addSessao&parametros=7b911e32-1432-45c3-8ee0-e316bad7a2f7|2|15/01/2017%2023:19:44|15/01/2017%2023:22:01|e8b5ed5c-d1bf-43c2-a7ad-cdb7699cc496|Outros|Teste%20|-7.99032|-34.8935
```

Os parametros são:

```
sys=TSE

usuario=teste

metodo=fw_addSessao

parametros=7b911e32-1432-45c3-8ee0-e316bad7a2f7|2|15/01/2017%2023:19:44|15/01/2017%2023:22:01|e8b5ed5c-d1bf-43c2-a7ad-cdb7699cc496|Outros|Teste%20|-7.99032|-34.8935
```

tudo é enviado em texto, o ultimo parâmetro tem concatenado varias informações como Id do registro, latitude, longitude e eu usei como delimitador o pipe "|" e pelo que eu estou notando o problema é ele, mais em minha rede interna não tem problema nenhum com o seu uso.

Comment: Você diz que no Amabiente de desenvolvimento não ocorre erros, isso quer dizer que quando disponibiliza para produção esse erro acontece? Você verificou se a URL está correta?

Comment: Sim a url esta correta, e uma vez que peguei ela do log do AE, fiz o seguinte onde tinha o "|" mudei para ";" ai o erro passou a ser o 500 que indica um erro no Servidor ou seja o POST chegou no servidor e como minha regra de negocio espera por um delimitador e chegou outro a rotina quebrou.

Comment: Tenta usar o URL ENCODE. Esse problema que está dando é requisição. Você não ta fazendo a requisição corretamente no server.

Comment: Veja: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: Olá Ack Lay boa tarde, entendi bem seria para pegar o texto onde eu tenho varias informações concatenadas e fazer um encode nele? e no servidor um decode?

Comment: Exatamente. Tente fazer isso, talvez tenha alguns caracteres que estão entrando em conflito com caracteres padrões da URL e está dando problema na interpretação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro `400 Bad Request` ocorre quando servidor não pode compreender e processar a solicitação correspondente. Depois de ter conferir se a URL referente ao servidor esteja realmente correta, uma solução possível é codificar os parâmetros usando a classe [**URLEncoder**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html), para que não tenha conflito com algum carácter reservado. Veja como ficaria:

```
String parametroCodificado = URLEncoder.encode("?sys=TSE&usuario=teste&metodo=fw_addSessao&parametros=7b911e32-1432-45c3-8ee0-e316bad7a2f7|2|15/01/2017%2023:19:44|15/01/2017%2023:22:01|e8b5ed5c-d1bf-43c2-a7ad-cdb7699cc496|Outros|Teste%20|-7.99032|-34.8935", "utf-8");
String url = "http://200.187.136.7:8080/nova/fw.rule" + parametroCodificado ;
```

Para mais detalhes sobre `URLEncoder`, veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Comment: Meu caro Ack Lay, vc estava absolutamente certo, muito obrigado cara, valeu mesmo, salvou o dia